# trouble with CoCreateInstance method

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-services, atl

I want to test a `COM Service(EXE)` but i can't to retrieve correct `HRESULT` from `CoCreateInstance`.

My COM sample is `'ATLCOMService'` Microsoft sample. How to fix that ?

And client code is:

```
    void main()
    {
        HRESULT         hr;
        ISimpleObject *IFirstATL = NULL;

        hr = CoInitialize(0);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SimpleObject, NULL,
                CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                LIBID_ATLCOMServiceLib, (void**)&IFirstATL);
            //hr is: E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported.

            hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SimpleObject, NULL,
                CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                LIBID_ATLCOMServiceLib, (void**)&IFirstATL);
            //hr is: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                BSTR str;
                IFirstATL->HelloWorld(&str);
                cout << str << endl;

                IFirstATL->Release();
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "CoCreateInstance Failed." << endl;
            }
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
```

And IDs in header file is:

```
    #ifndef CLSID_DEFINED
    #define CLSID_DEFINED
    typedef IID CLSID;
    #endif // CLSID_DEFINED

    #define MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(type,name,l,w1,w2,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8) \
            const type name = {l,w1,w2,{b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8}}

    #endif !_MIDL_USE_GUIDDEF_

    MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(IID, 
    IID_ISimpleObject,0x1B877090,0x76CD,0x4EDE,0x81,0x15,0xEC,
    0x4C,0xCD,0x96,0x76,0xF3);


    MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(IID, LIBID_ATLCOMServiceLib,0xCC2CA6F0,0x2220,0x4D77,0xBA,
    0x46,0x4B,0xCB,0x62,0x15,0x6A,0x28);


    MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(IID, DIID__ISimpleObjectEvents,0x7DACF5E9,0x2885,0x4E4E,
    0x83,0xDD,0xCA,0x6C,0xC3,0xA8,0x8B,0x6D);


    MIDL_DEFINE_GUID(CLSID, 
    CLSID_SimpleObject,0x388F1C82,0xED00,0x4966,0x95,0x90,
    0x02,0xF6,0xB9,0xCC,0xA4,0x1B);

    #undef MIDL_DEFINE_GUID

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
```

And in below saw registry instance and service status:

Registry - CLSID :

[image: Registry - CLSID]

Registry - typeid :

[image: Registry - typeid]

and
Service Status :

[image: Service status]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't why CoCreateInstance return these result? and how to fix that?

Comment: Returns what results?

Comment: For an out-of-process server (don't do it), you must always have the proxy and stub registered so the interface can be marshalled across the process barrier.  If it is not then E_NOINTERFACE is the outcome when COM can't find a way to marshal.  The ATL project template auto-generates the PS project, ensure that was all built correctly and properly registered.  Get additional diagnostics from SysInternals' ProcMon, you'll see the client searching for the Interface registry key.  "Don't do it" is certainly the best advice, out-of-process is brittle and hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I comment my return value of CoCreateInstance in my code, please see that.

Comment: `CoCreateInstance` 4th argument is invalid, should be `__uuidof(ISimpleObject)` (or `IID_ISimpleObject`).

Comment: @RomanR.Yes, I had a bad mistake in calling the function. Thank you for your guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SimpleObject, 
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
            LIBID_ATLCOMServiceLib, // <<--- IID_ISimpleObject here?
            (void**)&IFirstATL);
        //hr is: E_NOINTERFACE No such interface supported.
```

Note that the fourth argument is supposed to be `IID` of the interface you are requesting, presumably `IID_ISimpleObject`. The API's returned error code suggests that you check if you request the correct interface: `E_NOINTERFACE` (or if it is correct then maybe the server erroneously does not implement it, or it is a marshaling issue).